# How to determine where your beer was really bottled?

Tags: brewing, bottling

I have long entertained gossip from self-proclaimed "beer connoisseurs" that the Guiness I am drinking is not really brewed in Ireland, nor the Beck's from Germany.

I would imagine that where you are in the world really does determine where your particular bottle of macro brand X was bottled, so my question is how can you determine the true origin of the bottle -- can you trust the location on the bottle next to "brewed and bottled by..."?

Comment: If you brewed your own, you would have total control over that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The can/bottle is required to have country of origin listed on it.

Most US Guinness Extra Stout is brewed in either Toronto or New Brunswick, depending on the contract brewer. All of the Guinness Draught is brewed in their historic brewery in Dublin. However, debate abounds about whether the US recipe is different.

[image: Guinness Extra Stout Label]

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the small print. In the UK there is a Japanese beer called Asahi and on the front it has Japanese kanji writing and "IMPORTED" in big letters. But reading the small print on the side it says it is brewed in the Czech republic.